# how to setup Logging for MYSQL stored procedures

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net-mvc-3, debugging, logging

I am currently using MVC3(C#) and calling MYSQL stored procedures. I have developed quite alot already but do not have any logging setup. I want to know how can i go about setting up MYSQL logging to a specific directory. I want to monitor errors, and debug my stored procedures.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the following article from Dr.Dobb's journal: [Debugging MySQL Stored Procedures](http://www.drdobbs.com/database/218100564)

Comment: Thanks, i have read it, and have just added the following into my SP: DECLARE Exit Handler for SQLEXCEPTION BEGIN call saveAndLog(thingId, 'Exception - search_projects'); END; However, when i do a select from tmplog or select * from log, it doesnt exist. I expect the log(permanent table) to be in the schema im using. But it not. Any ideas ? thanks